# ArcGIS Dashboard - Popup : Not displaying all results

Tags: arcgis-server, operations-dashboard

I am using ArcGIS Dashboard Operations. I published the servie from ArGIS Pro.
After Publishing, I added the layers in the web map and WebMap used in the Dashboard Operation.
Issue:
List called Location and corresponding values like Hospitals will be shown in the map. But when I click the hospitals symbol in the web map, Pop-up comes up with one record. Actually, The hospital symbols 15 records. In the pop-up there is Button for forwarding the data.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you need to Configure the Pop-up. The Dashboard uses the webmap pop-ups. So, you need to configure them in the webmap. Back in your webmap:
[image]

From here you have a few options to configure. Make sure you include all the fields you want displayed from here.
[image]